# Copy a java list with a limit of entries

Tags: java, list, collections, clone

I would like to create a new `List<Object>` from a simple `List<Object>` only for the 20 first  entries.

```
//my first array
List<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList<Staff>();

staffs.add(new Staff(...));
staffs.add(new Staff(...));
staffs.add(new Staff(...));
staffs.add(new Staff(...));


List<Staff> second = magicMethodForClone(staffs,20);
```

I'd like to know if a method like `magicMethodForClone` exists or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
List<Staff> second = new ArrayList<Staff>(staffs.subList(0, 20));
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the subList function.

Answer (score 34):

`List.subList(0, 20)` will throw an Exception if your list contains less than 20 elements.

**With Java 8:**

You can use [Stream.limit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-):

```
List<Staff> second = staffs.stream().limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**With Java 7 or lower:**

You can use Guava's [Iterables.limit()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) to get all available elements but no more than 20:

```
List<Staff> second = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.limit(staffs, 20));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment ~ I'll try this next time !

Comment: Also with Guava, List<Staff> second = FluentIterable.from(staffs).limit(20).toList();